# Should a REST API parameter ever influence which other parameters are required?

Tags: rest, swagger

For instance, I can create a vehicle, and must give it a type which can be "automobile" or "airplane".  Automobiles require a tire size parameter and airplanes require a wingspan parameter.  Similar question regarding whether a REST API parameter should ever influence which properties are required in the response.

```
  /vehicles:
    post:
      summary: Creates a vehicle
      description: Adds a new vehicle of given type.
      parameters:
        - name: vehicle (what is the purpose of this????)
          in: body
          description: The vehicle to create.
          schema:
            required:
              - type
              - speed
              - color
            properties:
              type:
                type: string
              speed:
                type: interger
              color:
                type: string
              wingspan:
                type: string
              tiresize:
                type: string
      responses:
        204:
          description: Vehicle succesfully created.
        400:
          description: Vehicle couldn't have been created.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this happens in practice, it is best avoided as it makes it difficult to document your API. This is particularly true if you are using a documentation technology such as Swagger which does not allow these "conditionally required" parameters. By adding them, you are actually adding extra semantics to your API which are not documented in the Swagger docs.

A better approach is, instead of having a "type" parameter of different vehicle types, just use a separate URL for each type. This will allow you to properly document the required/optional parameters for each vehicle type.

```
/vehicles/automobile:
  post:
    parameters:
      schema:
        required:
          - tyresize
        properties:
          tyresize:
            type: string
/vehicles/airplane:
  post:
    parameters:
      schema:
        required:
          - wingspan
        properties:
          wingspan:
            type: string
```

Comment: Thanks tonicsoft.  I can vouch that it happens in practice as I was doing it!  After getting into Swagger, I felt I maybe shouldn't, and appreciate your validation.  Side note...  Does your configuration need an `name: automobile` and `in: body`?  I am reading https://apihandyman.io/writing-openapi-swagger-specification-tutorial-part-2-the-basics/, and it always adds a name, but I don't know the purpose.  Thanks

Comment: Glad you found it helpful. Yes I believe the configuration always needs a name (sorry for my sloppy example). All parameters require a name, just like methods in object oriented code. The name is so that you can actually provide the value of the parameter when you use the API: `curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"vehicle": .... }'`

Comment: Thanks again tonicsoft.  Your comment showed `curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"vehicle": .... }'`.  I take it if expanded you mean `curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"vehicle": { {"speed":123, "color": "blue", "wingspan": 321} }' 'http://example.com/vehicles/airplane'`.  Why wouldn't `curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"speed":123, "color": "blue", "wingspan": 321}' 'http://example.com/vehicles/airplane'` work, and the object passed becomes the (sorry, all I know) PHP $_POST super global variable?

Comment: For your second example to work, you would have to have THREE parameters (speed, color, wingspan) each of which should have it's own name, descriction and in: body properties. Instead, you have set up ONE parameter call vehicle, which is a JSON object which the schema you describe.